# JSON parsing android doesn't work always

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have a json file that needs to be parsed, but the standard json parser doesn't work, I dont know why. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, can someone help me with this?

This is the parser class:

```
public class GeoJSONDeserializer {

public static Route routeFromGeoJsonDictionary(JSONObject json)
{
    Route route = new Route();

    try {
        JSONArray features = json.getJSONArray("features");

        for (int i = 0; i < features.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject geometry = features.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry");

            if (geometry.getString("type").equals("LineString"))
            {
                route.paths.add(routePathFromLineStringFeature(features.getJSONObject(i)));
            } else if (geometry.getString("type").equals("Point"))
            {
                route.pois.add(poiFromPointFeature(features.getJSONObject(i)));
            } else if (geometry.getString("type").equals("Polygon"))
            {
                route.paths.add(routeAnnotationFromPolygonFeature(features.getJSONObject(i)));
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e)
    {}




    return route;
}

public static Path routePathFromLineStringFeature(JSONObject json)
{
    Path path = new Path();

    try {
        JSONObject geometry = json.getJSONObject("geometry");

        JSONArray lineStringCoordinates = geometry.getJSONArray("coordinates");

        for (int i = 0; i < lineStringCoordinates.length(); i++) {

            String coordinatePair = lineStringCoordinates.getString(i);

            String[] coords =
                    coordinatePair.substring(1, coordinatePair.length() - 2).split(",");

            double lat = Double.parseDouble(coords[0]);
            double lon = Double.parseDouble(coords[1]);

            LatLng point = new LatLng(lon, lat);

            path.coordinates.add(point);
        }


    } catch (Exception e)
    {}


    return path;
}


public static Path routeAnnotationFromPolygonFeature(JSONObject json)
{
    Path path = new Path();

    try {
        JSONObject geometry = json.getJSONObject("geometry");

        JSONArray lineStringCoordinates = json.getJSONArray("coordinates");

        for (int i = 0; i < lineStringCoordinates.length(); i++) {

            String coordinatePair;

            if (i >= lineStringCoordinates.length())
            {
                coordinatePair = lineStringCoordinates.getString(0);
            } else {
                coordinatePair = lineStringCoordinates.getString(i);
            }

            String[] coords =
                    coordinatePair.substring(1, coordinatePair.length() - 2).split(",");

            double lat = Double.parseDouble(coords[0]);
            double lon = Double.parseDouble(coords[1]);

            LatLng point = new LatLng(lon, lat);

            path.coordinates.add(point);
        }


    } catch (Exception e)
    {}


    return path;
}

public static POI poiFromPointFeature(JSONObject json)
{
    POI poi = new POI();

    try {
        JSONObject geometry = json.getJSONObject("geometry");
        Log.e("no parsed", geometry.toString());
        JSONObject properties = json.getJSONObject("properties");

        poi.title = properties.getString("name");
        poi.name = properties.getString("title");
        poi.subtitle = properties.getString("desc");

        try{
            JSONArray coordinates = geometry.getJSONArray("coordinates");
            poi.coordinates = new LatLng(coordinates.getDouble(1), coordinates.getDouble(0));
            Log.e("parsed", coordinates.toString());
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }

    } catch (Exception e)
    {}

    return poi;
}}
```

Then here is my log output:

[link to the log file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPmGN.png)

You can see some of the unparsed strings are parsed and some are not. It's not a random issue, as it happens always to the same ones.

Here is a link to the json file:

[Json file download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lkwrguvdh5d0vha/fietsroute-verdronken-dorpen.geojson?dl=0)

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: In your `poiFromPointFeature(JSONObject json)` in your empty catch output what the error is.  your error is happening before you try and parse the coordinates.

Comment: @JohnBoker but this line JSONObject geometry = json.getJSONObject("geometry"); does work you can see the log and its logging every line but when im trying to get the coordinates it doesnt work allways. right?

Comment: something between the "no parsed" and the "parsed" there is an exception.  you have part of that in a try catch that's showing the error, so i would think the part that's in the try..catch with no display of an error would contain the error

Comment: @JohnBoker found it!!! :) it was crashing because desc has no value sometimes so i use  `optString` instead of `getString` and now its returning null so it wont crash and the coordinates will parsed. Thanks for you help

Comment: one thing to note, you shouldnt put try..catch blocks around all your code with nothing in the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to use `optString` instead of `getString` so the parser will not crash in the try